# need clarification on this below key value pairs

Tags: mulesoft

Description:

1. Input should be json object.
2. Sort the key, value pairs alphabetically on basis of key.
3. Generate the output as mentioned in the example below.

***Example:***

Input:

```
{

"name":"<<your_name>>",

"age":"<<your_age>>",

"city":"<<your_city>>",

"role":"<<your_role>>"

}
```

Output:

```
age=<<your_age>>&city=<<your_city>>&name=<<your_name>>&<<your_role>>
```

***Note:*** Please send the input using postman and your code should work for any number of key, value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

First let me say that if you intend to use the as the query parameters string of an HTTP request it is not a good idea. It would make a lot more sense to use the HTTP Requester to just send each attribute with the requester as a query parameter. It will automatically apply URL encoding and handle the parameters.

Example:

```
<set-variable value='#[{
  name:"&lt;&lt;your_name&gt;&gt;",
  age:"&lt;&lt;your_age&gt;&gt;",
  city:"&lt;&lt;your_city&gt;&gt;",
  role:"&lt;&lt;your_role&gt;&gt;"
}]' doc:name="Set Variable" variableName="person"/>

<http:request method="GET"  config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/backend" >
    <http:query-params><![CDATA[#[vars.person]]]></http:query-params>
</http:request>
```

See how you just tell it to use the object to generate the query parameters. The output request will be:

```
GET /backend?name=%3C%3Cyour_name%3E%3E&age=%3C%3Cyour_age%3E%3E&city=%3C%3Cyour_city%3E%3E&role=%3C%3Cyour_role%3E%3E HTTP/1.1
```

If you absolutely feel that you have to build the query parameters string manually see below.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::URL
---
// it is not recommended to use this, use the HTTP Requester <http:query-params> instead
encodeURI(
    payload pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
        { key: key, value: value}
    )  
    orderBy( $.key )
    reduce ((val, acc = "") -> 
        acc ++ (if(sizeOf(acc) !=0) "&" else "") ++ val.key ++ "=" ++ val.value)
)
```